# How to add LinkedIn OAuth 2.0 authentication in iOS swift?

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, linkedin-api

I have implemented LinkedIn authentication with the Mobile SDK. But mobile SDK authentication is not working now. On LinkedIn's website, they have mentioned that "Our JavaScript and Mobile Software Development Kits (SDKs) will stop working. Developers will need to migrate to using OAuth 2.0 directly from their apps."

But they have not given exact steps to implement OAuth 2.0 authentication.

I have referred many websites and StackOverflow questions, but I didn't get exact steps to implement this as per the current issues of LinkedIn.

All answers given on StackOverflow was old when LinkedIn don't have these much issues. I've asked the question on LinkedIn help forum too, but they suggested me to ask a question on StackOverflow.

So can anyone suggest me the good tutorial or steps to implement OAuth 2.0?

I've tried with below code:

```
linkedInHelper.login(from: self, loadingTitleString: "Loading", completion: { (token) in
                    let alertVC = UIAlertController(title: "Success", message: "Your access token is : \(token)!", preferredStyle: .alert)
                    alertVC.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: { _ in
                        alertVC.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }))
                    self.present(alertVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }, failure: { (error) in
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }) {
                    print("Cancel")
                }
```

But still, it is not working. This gave me an error "bummer, something went wrong. the redirect_uri does not match the registered value".

As per some tutorials, I've also tried with below code:

```
let linkedinCredentilas = [
    "linkedInKey": "",
    "linkedInSecret": "",
    "redirectURL": "myapp://"
]

let linkedInConfig = LinkedInConfig(linkedInKey: linkedinCredentilas["linkedInKey"]!, linkedInSecret: linkedinCredentilas["linkedInSecret"]!, redirectURL: linkedinCredentilas["redirectURL"]!)
```

But I don't know that what should be the redirect URL.

I simply want to redirect the user to my app after authentication. I don't want to redirect the user to any website. So, in this case, what should I mention as a redirect URL?

Comment: Do not share your Client ID or Secret here.

Comment: use the swift ouath library. Here is the link: https://github.com/OAuthSwift/OAuthSwift

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing [3-legged OAuth2 or 2-legged OAuth2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/permissions?context=linkedin/context)?

The first step in OAuth2 is always to [create an OAuth2 Application](https://www.linkedin.com/developers/apps/new).  On LinkedIn it is a two-step process.  First you add the app, then you add the callback URL:

[image: step 1]
[image: step 2]
Once you complete this, you can use an Oauth2 flow. There are several decent OAuth2 libraries out there including [OAuthSwift](https://github.com/OAuthSwift/OAuthSwift)

LinkedIn has an [example here](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/v2/oauth2-client-credentials-flow#).

Comment: If I don't want to redirect the user to any website then what should I add as a redirect URL? I simply want to redirect the user back to my app.

Comment: @swapnilpatel it doesn't matter.  If you are using a WKWebView you can intercept the callback URL and store the result.

Comment: So I have to use WKWebView? And what should be the first URL which I have to open in WKWebView?

Comment: I have already created app into LinkedIn. But what should I do codewise into my iOS app? Can you please give me further details?